# Why limit site to "many desktop PCs" and no mention of laptops?

Tags: discussion

[FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq) says I can ask questions here when I manage **many desktop PCs**. What if I manage 100's of laptops?

Comment: Because professionals wouldn't split hairs like that.

Comment: @Chopper Not even an explanation?

Comment: How's this; closed as subjective and argumentative by Chopper3♦ 1 hour ago
It's impossible to objectively answer this question; questions of this type are too open ended and usually lead to confrontation and argument. Plus it's just an extremely stupid question.

Comment: @Cho That's offensive, but anyways, I simply wanted to know why exclude laptops? What's stupid about that?

Comment: It's stupid because nobody in their right mind would differentiate the two, it just says desktop because that's the word chosen, it limits nobody.

Comment: @Chopper Can you reword it then, to avoid further exposure on user stupidity?

Comment: If I did reword it I'd have to start with "I'm trying to create a needless argument over something anyone can see isn't an issue, but let's forget about using our brains for a moment...." - so best not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh hrm that probably needs to be changed. But yes 100's of laptops is just fine too :)

Comment: +1 for a civilized answer.

Answer (score 10):

I think the FAQ needs to be treated as a guideline, not a legalistic set of rules.  The point of that bullet is about administering a large set of similar systems.  I think it is probably adequate.

I believe it is would probably be obvious to most system admins that the bullet is about a large set of similar machines, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: It's worth noting that from what I've seen so far nobody else has had a problem with that wording and we see a fair number of questions relating to the administration of multiple laptops.